# UWSGI no module named uwsgi

Tags: python, django, websocket, uwsgi, wsgi

I hope you are doing well. I have problem with 
`import uwsgi`
Thanks for helping, my rabbitmq is working behind scene dont worry about it

I already installed uwsgi which version 2.0.15 and 2.0.18 and i tried still it does not work my purpose is import uwsgi and

```
uwsgi.websocket_handshake(
        env['HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY'],
        env.get('HTTP_ORIGIN', '')
    )
```

If i can not import uwsgi so i can not use uwsgi.websocker_handshake

```
"""Receive messages over from RabbitMQ and send them over the websocket."""

import sys

import pika
import uwsgi


def application(env, start_response):
    """Setup the Websocket Server and read messages off the queue."""
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')
    )
    channel = connection.channel()

    exchange = env['PATH_INFO'].replace('/', '')

    channel.exchange_declare(
        exchange=exchange, exchange_type='fanout'
    )

    # exclusive means the queue should be deleted once the connection is closed
    result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
    queue_name = result.method.queue  # random queue name generated by RabbitMQ

    channel.queue_bind(exchange=exchange, queue=queue_name)

    uwsgi.websocket_handshake(
        env['HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY'],
        env.get('HTTP_ORIGIN', '')
    )

    def keepalive():
        """Keep the websocket connection alive (called every 30 seconds)."""
        print('PING/PONG...')
        try:
            uwsgi.websocket_recv_nb()
            connection.add_timeout(30, keepalive)
        except OSError as error:
            connection.close()
            print(error)
            sys.exit(1)  # Kill process and force uWSGI to Respawn

    keepalive()

    while True:
        for method_frame, _, body in channel.consume(queue_name):
            try:
                uwsgi.websocket_send(body)
            except OSError as error:
                print(error)
                sys.exit(1)  # Force uWSGI to Respawn
            else:
                # acknowledge the message
                channel.basic_ack(method_frame.delivery_tag)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "websocket.py", line 6, in 
    import uwsgi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uwsgi'

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons and you install `uwsgi` for one Python but you run code with another Python.

Comment: Please show exactly how you installed it and how you are running this code.

Comment: https://danidee10.github.io/2018/01/13/realtime-django-5.html actually im following that guy may he can help more than me

Answer (score 2):

How do you start your code?

If you want to import uwsgi you have (if I recall correctly) to start the uwsgi executable, which will on its turn start the uwsgi workers. These uwsgi workers can then import uwsgi.